# Initializing an Array using lambda with conditions in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, lambda, initialization

### Info

I have an Item class file as follows:

```
class Item(var color:String, var numValue:Int, var drawableID:Int){
    init {
        color = this.color
        numValue = this.numValue
        drawableID = this.drawableID
    }
}
```

In the main code I create an array which contains 104 objects by default attributes:

```
var myItemClassArray = Array(104) { Item("", -99, -99) }
```

Also I have pictures in my drawable folder and I have their IDs in an array which is `drawablesIDs:Array<Int>`, and it contains 53 elements.

### Problem

I want to assign my Item attributes as in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFVsn.png I can do it for a similar problem (which has 106 objects and 53 drawables) with the code given in below:

```
        for (i in 0 until 106) {
            if (i < 13) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "kirmizi"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = i+1
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1]
            } else if (i in 13..25) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "siyah"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-13
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1]
            } else if (i in 26..38) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "yesil"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-26
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1]
            } else if (i in 39..51) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "mavi"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-39
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1]
            } else if (i in 52..64) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "kirmizi"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-52
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[(i+1)-52]
            } else if (i in 65..77) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "siyah"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-65
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1-65+13]
            } else if (i in 78..90) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "yesil"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-78
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1-78+26]
            } else if (i in 91..103) {
                myItemClassList[i+2].color = "mavi"
                myItemClassList[i+2].numValue = (i+1)-91
                myItemClassList[i+2].drawableID = drawablesIDs[i+1-91+39]
            } else {
                myItemClassList[0].color = "sahte"
                myItemClassList[0].drawableID = drawablesIDs[0]
                myItemClassList[1].color = "sahte"
                myItemClassList[1].drawableID = drawablesIDs[0]
            }
        }
```

***Is there a cleaner way to do this?***

One can use lambda expression to create an array. For example:

```
val test = Array(28){i-> examples[i]}
```

This works fine with one "i" parameter. But if I want to try something like this:

```
val test = Array(28){if(i<13)-> examples[i]}
```

it gives me an error because of it's syntax is wrong.

### More Simple Question

Let's say we have an array which has numbers from 0 to 28 like this:

```
val testNumbers= Array(28){i->i}
```

Now I want to create an array which will contain numbers from 0 to 10 using lambda.
How do I this:

```
val player6 = Array(10){(it<10) -> testNumbers[it]} // gives an syntax error
```

Comment: For your simple question, a simple answer. Use .filter { it < 11 }

Comment: You could use the `when` statement, but it won't shorten this code very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could gather from your picture, I've made these three assumptions:

- The numValue is grouped in groups of 13 items
- Each group receives a color in the order: kirmizi -> siyah -> yesil -> mavi, then it cycles again
- The drawable IDs cycles every 52 items

Based on this, I came up with the following solution:

```
data class Item(var color: String = "", var numValue: Int = -99, var drawableId: Int = -99)

fun main() {
    val colors = listOf("kirmizi", "siyah", "yesil", "mavi")
    val drawableIDs = (0..52).toList()  // This is just a stub. in your case it will be your drawable lists

    val edgeCase = arrayListOf(Item("sahte", drawableId = drawableIDs[0]), Item("sahte", drawableId = drawableIDs[0]))

    val pattern = (0 until 104)
        .map { index ->  Pair(index, index / 13) }
        .map { (index, group) -> 
            Item(
                color = colors[group % 4], 
                numValue = index+1, 
                drawableId = drawableIDs[(index % 52) + 1]
            ) 
        }

    val total = pattern + edgeCase 
    total.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

You can play around with it on this [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/U8s0TBneN).

> **Is there a cleaner way to do this?**

From what I gather, you want to initialize only the first 13 values of a contiguous array with 28 spaces, leaving the rest with either their default values or null.

The reason why your code doesn't work is because the `Array` initializer expects you to return an object. the `if` block by itself is not an expression in kotlin, so it doesn't evaluate to a value, so you need to provide an `else` branch for it to work.

```
val examples = Array(28) { if (i < 13) examples[i] else defaultExample }
```

This is stated in the [Kotlin documentation for control flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html):

> *If you're using if as an expression rather than a statement (for example, returning its value or assigning it to a variable), the expression is required to have an else branch.*

---

> **More simple question**

In this case you could just use [take](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html):

```
// If you don't want to modify it
val player6 = testNumbers.take(10)
                   .toTypedArray()  // Since take returns a List, you need to turn it back into an array

// If you want to modify the items
val player6 = testNumbers.take(10)
                    .map { value -> modifyNumber(value) }
                    .toTypedArray()
```

**Tip:** In kotlin if you declare your constructor parameter with `val` or `var` they are already attributes from your class and you don't need to initialize manually in the `init` block.

```
/*
 * You don't need to do this:
 * class Item(var color: String, var numValue: Int, var drawableId: Int) {
 *    init {
 *      this.color = color
 *      this.numValue = numValue
 *      this.drawableId = drawableId
 *    }
 * }
 */

// Kotlin already does it for you
class Item(var color: String, var numValue: Int, var drawableId: Int)

fun main() {
    val myitem = Item("blue", 20, 100)

    println(myitem.color)
    println(myitem.numValue)
    println(myitem.drawableId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution :

```
fun getColor(i: Int) = when (i) {
  in 0..1 -> "sahte"
  in 2..13, in 52..64 -> "kirmizi"
  in 65..77, in 13..25 -> "siyah"
  in 26..38, in 78..90 -> "yesil"
  in 39..51, in 91..103 -> "mavi"
  else -> ""
}

fun getNumValue(i: Int) = when (i) {
  in 0..1 -> -99
  in 2..13 -> i - 1
  in 13..25 -> (i - 1) - 13
  in 26..38 -> (i - 1) - 26
  in 39..51 -> (i - 1) - 39
  in 52..64 -> (i - 1) - 52
  in 65..77 -> (i - 1) - 65
  in 78..90 -> (i - 1) - 78
  in 91..103 -> (i - 1) - 91
  else -> -99
}

fun getDrawableID(i: Int) = when (i) {
  in 0..1 -> drawablesIDs[0]
  in 2..13, in 13..25, in 26..38, in 39..51 -> drawablesIDs[i - 1]
  in 52..64 -> drawablesIDs[(i - 1) - 52]
  in 65..77 -> drawablesIDs[i - 1 - 65 + 13]
  in 78..90 -> drawablesIDs[i - 1 - 78 + 26]
  in 91..103 -> drawablesIDs[i - 1 - 91 + 39]
  else -> -99
}

val myItemClassArray = Array(104) {
  Item(getColor(it), getNumValue(it), getDrawableID(it))
}
```

Maybe there is some mistakes in the different ranges.

The main advantages are :

- each mapping is testable independently
- no mutability